# data frame in r is used to store tabular data?

Tags: r

I am facing these two questions, and I am not sure the first one' A is correct or not. Whether my answer to these two questions correct?

1. A “dataframe” in R is…   (A, C)
   a.  Used to store tabular data
   b.  Has columns that are all the same data type
   c.  Has labeled rows and columns
   d.  All of the above
   e.  None of the above
2. A “list” in R is… (B, C)
   a.  A vector that can contain only objects of one class
   b.  A vector that can contain objects of any class
   c.  A vector that can contain data frames
   d.  All of the above
   e.  None of the above

Comment: A `list` contains zero or more "things", where often a "thing" is a vector of some time. Each of these vectors within a `list` may be a different type, but all data within each vector must be the same type. A `data.frame` is just a special-case of a `list`, where all elements are simple vectors and of the same length. Row names are never required, and many discourage the use of row names (instead recommending putting said information in a column).

Comment: First statement. Dataframe can have lists inside it, so is not "classical tabular data", it can have different data types, and rows don't have to be labeled. So, non of above. Second statement: FALSE, FALSEFALSE: list is not a vector, but can contain dataframes and all classes (I think).

Comment: @Mislav - `is.vector(list(1))` is `TRUE` - so a list is a vector. Also `vector(3, mode="list")` returns a list.

Comment: True, I wanted to say they are not the same. But you are right.

Comment: @r2evans but when I `df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "b", "c"))
labels(df)` It  returns:[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3"

[[2]]
[1] "x" "y"

Comment: What do you think is inconsistent between my statement and those results? The first of the two (`[[1]]`) represents row names; lacking anything explicit, they are `character` representations of the row number, and I say again that using/changing these is discouraged by many. Try `rownames(df) <- c("1","3","2")` and see the difference between `df[3,]` and `df["3",]`.

Comment: @Mislav could you please explain a little more about ' Dataframe can have lists inside it, so is not "classical tabular data" '? can you give me an example? thank you